Typeorm subscriber does not use latest data
I wrote a subsriber that listen for review changes and updates the average rating in the target column.
import { EntityTargetType } from '@src/core/enums/entity-target-type.enum';
import { CourseEntity } from '@src/modules/course/entities/course.entity';
import { HomeworkEntity } from '@src/modules/homework/entities/homework.entity';
import { LectureEntity } from '@src/modules/lecture/entities/lecture.entity';
import { ReviewEntity } from '@src/modules/review/entities/review.entity';
import { EntitySubscriberInterface, EventSubscriber, InsertEvent, RemoveEvent, UpdateEvent } from 'typeorm';

@EventSubscriber()
export class ReviewSubscriber implements EntitySubscriberInterface<ReviewEntity> {
  constructor() {}

  listenTo() {
    return ReviewEntity;
  }

  async afterUpdate(event: UpdateEvent<ReviewEntity>) {
    await this.updateTarget(event);
  }

  async afterRemove(event: RemoveEvent<ReviewEntity>) {
    await this.updateTarget(event);
  }

  async afterInsert(event: InsertEvent<ReviewEntity>) {
    await this.updateTarget(event);
  }

  async updateTarget(event: UpdateEvent<ReviewEntity> | RemoveEvent<ReviewEntity> | InsertEvent<ReviewEntity>) {
    const queryRunner = event.connection.createQueryRunner();
    await queryRunner.connect();
    await queryRunner.startTransaction();

    console.log(event.entity);

    try {
      let lecture: LectureEntity | null = null;
      const query = queryRunner.manager.createQueryBuilder(ReviewEntity, 'review');
      query.select('COALESCE(ROUND(AVG(review.rating), 2), 0)', 'rating');
      query.addSelect('COALESCE(COUNT(review.id), 0)', 'count');

      if (event.entity.targetType === EntityTargetType.LECTURE_BOOK) {
        query.leftJoin('lecture_book_entity', 'lectureBook', 'lectureBook.id = review.targetId');
        query.leftJoin('lectureBook.lecture', 'lecture');

        lecture = await queryRunner.manager.findOne(LectureEntity, {
          where: { bookings: { id: event.entity.targetId } },
        });

        if (!lecture) {
          throw new Error(`Lecture not found for booking id ${event.entity.targetId}`);
        }

        query.where('lecture.id = :lectureId', { lectureId: lecture.id });
      } else {
        query.where('review.targetId = :targetId', { targetId: event.entity.targetId });
      }

      // Perform a select query to get the latest review information
      const res = await query.getRawOne();
      const ratings = {
        ratingsCount: res['count'],
        ratingsAvg: res['rating'],
      };

      console.log(ratings, lecture?.id);

      if (event.entity.targetType === EntityTargetType.COURSE) {
        await queryRunner.manager.update(CourseEntity, { id: event.entity.targetId }, ratings);
      } else if (event.entity.targetType === EntityTargetType.HOMEWORK) {
        await queryRunner.manager.update(HomeworkEntity, { id: event.entity.targetId }, ratings);
      } else if (event.entity.targetType === EntityTargetType.LECTURE_BOOK) {
        if (lecture) {
          await queryRunner.manager.update(LectureEntity, { id: lecture.id }, ratings);
        }
      }

      await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
    } catch (err) {
      await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();
      console.error('Error updating target:', err);
    } finally {
      await queryRunner.release();
    }
  }
}


The problem is that when I update review from 2 to 3, the res stores the old rating not the new one so I guess rating table in query is somehow not up to date. Byut why and how to fix that?
Interestingly, when I replace
    const queryRunner = event.connection.createQueryRunner();

by
    const queryRunner = event.queryRunner

then the res average is fine but then when trying to perform update I've got:
QueryRunnerAlreadyReleasedError: Query runner already released. Cannot run queries anymore.


With any method ReviewSubscriber when you start making changes through TypeORM (update, commit, ...) in this place the previous request is completed FIRST, and only then your changes are made. Your changes in turn trigger a call to afterUpdate -> updateTarget. That is, the old updateTarget method has not yet completed, the new one has already been called.
To resolve the issues I used something like this:


async updateTarget(event: ...): Promise<...> {
  const manager = event.connection.manager;
  const query = ``;
  if (query != event.query) { ... }
  return event;
}



